# cannot delete nodes and visualize in cayley database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am playing little bit with cayley database and I run to some problems. I am using last version 0.4, with nodejs, npm package (https://www.npmjs.org/package/cayley), mongoDB and angular.

Anyway first problem is that I cannot visualize any nodes. I am getting error "**Uncaught The node must have a string id**.". When I run **g.V().All()** I get:

```
{
 "result": [
  {
  "id": "alice"
  },
  {
   "id": "bob"
  },
  {
   "id": "follows"
  },
  {
   "id": "John"
  },
  {
   "id": "Subject Node"
  },
  {
   "id": "Object Node"
  },
  {
   "id": "Predicate Node"
  }
 ]
}
```

As I see it all my nodes has string ID, maybe I am missing something.

Second problem is deleting nodes or quads. As I mention I am using npm package and also the example from bottom

```
client.delete([{
  subject: "Subject Node",
  predicate: "Predicate Node",
  object: "Object Node"
}], function(err, body, res) {

});
```

When I run it I get successful message that I have deleted 1 tripple but nodes are still there. Also quad. One thing I noticed is that in quads appeared this:

```
"Deleted" : [
    NumberLong(9)
]
```

**EDIT 1:**

I sucessfully visualized data:

```
<moving> <name> "Moving" .
<moving> <description> "Basic object action." .
<moving> <parent> <walking> .
<moving> <parent> <running> .
<walking> <name> "Walking" .
<walking> <description> "Slow moving." .
<running> <name> "Running" .
<running> <description> "Fast moving." .
```

by running this:

```
moving = g.M("moving")
g.V().As("source").Follow(moving).Out("parent").Out("name").As("target").All()
```

Comment: you didn't provide dataset, so it's hard to do any debugging.

Comment: I beliave I provided enaugh information to understand the problem. Anyway as it is mentioned by EDIT 1, I found the command and I was able to visualize data. I was not able to solve problem with deleintg so I used rdfstorejs for storing and d3js for visualizing.